# On my Inspiron 5551 I cannot boot Linux from an external SSD

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

On my Inspiron 5551 I cannot boot Ubuntu-Studio 22.04.2 LTS from a USB 3.0 external SSD. The system was installed using the "live" version.

The problem is that the BIOS (UEFI) cannot find the disk with the system connected to the USB 3.0 port (left side of the computer).
If I connect the drive to USB 2.0 (right side) then the drive is visible as both UEFI and Legacy.

I have also noticed this property that when I connect for example a memory card with RescueDisk (or any other system with a UEFI partition) to the USB 3.0 through a HAMA reader with USB 3.0
the BIOS does not detect this card, however if I connect the *same* card via a USB 2.0 reader, BIOS sees the card.

My conclusion is that there is a problem with the USB 3.0 port.
Of course when I enable "Security boot" then the disk is visible
but I cannot boot system from this disk.

Computer information:

System name:        Dell
  System manufacturer:    Dell Inc.
  System model:       Inspiron 5551
  System type:        x64-based PC
  System storage unit:    06D7
  System version/date: BIOS Dell Inc. A04, 22.01.2018
  SMBIOS version:     2.7
  Embedded controller version: 1.01
  BIOS system mode:   UEFI
  Motherboard manufacturer: Dell Inc.
  Motherboard product:    0WT4NH
  Motherboard version:    A00

Comment: Try Ubuntu instead of just a Linux kernel. It should be easier, because Ubunu has a bootloader and many other useful tools apart from Linux.

Comment: When writing LINUX, I meant Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Hmm..., why not just write Ubuntu Studio? You should always provide the name and release of the distro. For example Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I provided the Ubuntu Studio version in the main post. But the described problem applies to ANY type of LINUX system, e.g. systemrescue.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 implies you've not applied security fixes, and are possibly using a *revoked* key (the newer key was provided as part of the 22.04.3 upgrades which you should have received awhile back and from your provided details maybe haven't applied, which may explain why if you have Secure-Boot enabled as you've not updated from the now revoked key). Turning *Secure-Boot* may allow boot, so you can apply all upgrades, then if this is the issue, you can reboot & turn Secure-Boot back on.

Comment: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ shows the 22.04.3 release date as for ISO, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date.